# Trouble loading json-io external jar in Android application

Tags: java, android, jar, dalvik

I'm trying to send and receive a class via the JsonReader and JsonWriter classes. There is a server application running Java, sending a MenuItem object via these lines:

```
     MenuItem asdf = new MenuItem (1, "SAMPLE", 2.32);
     JsonWriter obj = new JsonWriter(server.getOutputStream());
     bj.write(asdf);
```

And the other side running on Android receives as follows:

```
JsonReader obj = new JsonReader(clisock.getInputStream());
tmp = (MenuItem) obj.readObject();
obj.close();
```

The problem is that the dalvik vm says it cannot find the json-io class JReader, as indicated by the trace :

```
08-25 09:25:25.434: E/dalvikvm(560): Could not find class 'com.cedarsoftware.util.io.JsonReader', referenced from method com.example.testdrive.MainActivity$FetchMenu.doInBackground
```

I have included the json-io jar file in both the server and client's build path, and have ticked the jar file in the "Order and Export" section of Eclipse. The IDE shows no errors and runs the application, but it still crashes. Any suggestions are welcome ... I apologize for not being able to explain better. I can provide more source, if need be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is happening because you do not have the json-io.jar file in your class path on the side that is doing the reading.  The calling code in MainActivity$FetchMenu.doInBackground is not able to find the class com.cedarsoftware.util.io.JsonReader.

`Could not find class 'com.cedarsoftware.util.io.JsonReader', referenced from method com.example.testdrive.MainActivity$FetchMenu.doInBackground`

Make sure to get the latest copy of json-io from GitHub at https://github.com/jdereg/json-io